# Enumerate through a DictionaryAdapter passed to OnFlushDirty

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord, castle-dictionaryadapter

I am attempting to use the `OnFlushDirty` method of a `Castle.ActiveRecord` object in order to implement generic auditing of changes:

```
protected override bool OnFlushDirty(object id, 
                                     IDictionary previousState, 
                                     IDictionary currentState, 
                                     NHibernate.Type.IType[] types
                                    )
```

On execution, OnFlushDirty is passed a `Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.DictionaryAdapter` for each of the `previousState` and `currentState` parameters.

Unfortunately `DictionaryAdapter` does not support the `GetEnumerator()` method, throwing a `NotSupportedException`.

1. Should I be expecting a `DictionaryAdapter` to be passed into OnFlushDirty in the first place?; and
2. Assuming I should, how can I enumerate through the Key/Value pairs within the `DictionaryAdapter` in order to compare previous and current states for auditing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DictionaryAdapter` includes a Key collection which can be enumerated normally with the Key then being applied to retrieve its Value.

Sample solution code:

```
foreach (var entry in currentState.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(currentState[entry]);
}
```